# has_many and belongs_to with join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I have `User`s and `Truck`s. I want the ability to say `@truck.drivers << @users` and `@user.truck = @truck`.

The solution is simple until I want the relationship to be stored in a join table.

```
# tables
:users
  :id

:truck_drivers
  :user_id
  :truck_id

:truck
  :id
```

I've gotten it to where I can say `@truck.drivers << @user` and `@user.trucks << @truck`, but I would like to limit a user to occupy one truck at a time, for my sanity.

Is it possible? A has_many/belongs_to with a join table? Or should I try a different approach? I'm not using a third model for the join table. It's just a table. Here's what I have so far.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :trucks,
    join_table: :truck_drivers, # points to the table
    class_name: :Truck # looks for the truck model in the table
end

class Truck < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_and_belongs_to_many :drivers,
    join_table: :truck_drivers,
    class_name: :User
end
```

The reason I need a join table in the first place is because each `User` can have many `Role`s: Admin, Manager, Driver, Customer Service, etc. I thought it didn't make sense to add a `truck_id` to all the users if all the users are not going to be using trucks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you ought to be able to do something like:

```
@user.trucks << @truck unless @user.trucks.any?
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a standard strategy with rails using the  `:through` keyword.

rails documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

**Make a model called** `TruckUser` with `truck_id` and `user_id`

then edit your classes:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :truck_users
  has_many :trucks, through: :truck_users
end

class Truck < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :truck_users
  has_many :drivers, through: :truck_users
end

class TruckUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :truck
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to limit one truck per user?

Comment: @CruzNunez you've written `has_any_belongs_to_many` both ways.

Comment: are you saying you want a truck to have many users, but a user should only have one truck?

Comment: OR saying keep the database structure as-is but apply a limit?

Comment: I know i have habtm both ways. But I asked if I could get it to function like a belongs_to. How do you apply the limit?

Comment: `belongs_to` means you have the foreign key...so it has to be a limit of one

Comment: yeah but i think he eventually wants to have many<>many but for now just limit it